# What is the probability of catching an enchanted book in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I have an enchanted fishing rod with Lure III, Luck of The Sea III, Mending, and Unbreaking III, how many successful catches on average will it take to get an enchanted book?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to get enchanted books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272380/fastest-way-to-get-enchanted-books)

Comment: @Asadefa This is not a duplicate of that question. This question asks for the probability to get an enchante book from fishing, while the other question is asking what the most efficient way to get enchanted books is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acording to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing) the odds of catching an enchanted book is 1.6% with luck of the sea III. Meaning for every hundred catches, you would catch 1-2 enchanted books on average. Unbreaking and mending do not affect the rate at which enchanted books are caught at all. Lure make it take less long to catch something, and Luck of the sea increases the chance that what you will catch will be valuable. Hope this helps.